# Compound interest calculator homework

Tags: java, beginner, homework, calculator, finance

I am a  beginner at coding Java and am having a tough time understanding what is wrong with this code. This is an assignment I had posted about earlier and I also went to a Java tutor at my school for help after having issues communicating with my actual teacher (I am an online student). She gave me 10%. I will include instructions and the criteria she offered when she said I could "r&r", revise & resubmit. She seems to want something extremely specific and I'm not exactly sure what she wants.

> INSTRUCTIONS
>
> Create a Java file called CompoundInterestYourLastName. Write a method
>   called `computeBalance( )` that computes the balance of a bank account
>   with a given initial balance and interest rate, after a given number
>   of years. Assume interest is compounded yearly.
>
> You can use the standard calculator here to check your results (note
>   that you'll have to change the dropdown to compound the interest
>   yearly): 
>   http://www.thecalculatorsite.com/finance/calculators/compoundinterestcalculator.php
>
> Use a loop to control the iterations through the years in your method.
>
> Your method should return a double value.
>
> In your main method, run the following tests to verify your method is
>   working correctly.
>
> ```
> System.out.printf("Your total is $%.2f", computeBalance(1000, .045, 3));
> // should return $1141.17
> System.out.printf("\nYour total is $%.2f", computeBalance(2000, .03, 5));
> // should return $2318.55
> System.out.printf("\nYour total is $%.2f", computeBalance(3000, .01, 10));
> // should return $3313.87
> ```
>
> Pay close attention to your parameters to make sure they match the
>   test datat!
>
> *Note:  Your methods should have this exact signature line, including the correct spelling, capitalization and parameter types.  Otherwise,
>   when I run the test to check the file, your methods will fail and
>   you'll have to revise.
>
> When you are finished with your file, upload it to Blackboard.  This
>   program is worth 10 points.

CRITERIA SHE OFFERED: Use a simple formula in your loop to return the results outlined in the assignment. You don't need to use Math.pow to get this to work. r&r

```
 // Tori Tidwell
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.lang.Math;
 public class CompoundInterestTidwell {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("   Inital Balance Amount:     ");
    double P = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("   Interest rate:     ");
    double r = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("   Number of years in account:     ");
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    double compInt = computeBalance(P, r, t);

    System.out.printf("   Your new balance is $%.2f", compInt);
    sc.close();
}

public static double computeBalance(double P, double r, int t) {
    // Formula for compounding interest
    // A = P(1+(r/n))^(n(t))
    // Java tutor in AAC told me to use c instead of n*t. Math worked after this.

    double compInt = 0;
    for(int c = 0; c <= t; c++ ) {

        compInt = P*Math.pow((1+r/100), c);



}
    return compInt;
}

}
```

Comment: Within your loop, you overwrite `compInt`, so only the last loop iteration is meaningful. Either remove the loop, or use a simple multiplication inside the loop,

Comment: What kind of multiplication? Using a carrot sign like in math doesn't work. Searching the internet gives me Math.pow again. I need to know more descriptively what else I should be doing, thanks.

Comment: For example, a 4% annual interest rate means multiplying by 1.04 (104%) every year. You do this in a loop t times, with t the number of years. This is equivalent to multiplying once by pow(1.04,t).

Answer (score 3):

First, to fix your formula:

`r` probably shouldn't be divided by 100, since the argument is `.045` in one of the examples, which I verified to mean 4.5% rather than 0.045%.

Now, the loop logic:

Your current code replaces `compInt` each time the for loop runs, so it does something like this.

Example: P=1000, r=0.045, t=3

```
compInt = 0
compInt = 1000 * 1.045 ^ 0
compInt = 1000 * 1.045 ^ 1
compInt = 1000 * 1.045 ^ 2
compInt = 1000 * 1.045 ^ 3
```

There is no need to perform any of the calculations except for the last line.

However, since your teacher wants you to not use `Math.pow` and use a loop. So think: what gets repeated when you do `Math.pow`? Multiplication, of course. So you simply multiply the principal by `1+r` for each year.

Since it's homework, I'm not going to post the revised code, but I hope I've given you an idea of where to go.